# SeekBar can work but then it can't auto run the seekbar progress

Tags: java, android-studio

My SeekBar can work but then it can't auto-run the SeekBar progress
when I clicked on the SeekBar I will auto move to the position with an overlay player. and the runnable thread does not on the SeekBar
the line below is the code of my SeekBar

```
        positionBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
                new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                        if(fromUser && progress != 100) {
                            player.getDuration();
                            player.seekTo(progress);
                            positionBar.setProgress(progress);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "seekbar progress: " + progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else {
                            progress = 0;
                            positionBar.setProgress(progress);
                            Song nextSong = songCollection.getNextSong(songId);
                            if(nextSong != null){
                                songId = nextSong.getId();
                                title = nextSong.getTitle();
                                artist = nextSong.getArtist();

                                fileLink = nextSong.getFileLink();
                                coverArt = nextSong.getCoverArt();
                                url = BASE_URL + fileLink;
                                displaySong(title,artist,coverArt);
                                stopActivities();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        //
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seekbar touch started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        // player.seekTo(musicPostion);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seekbar touch stop!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        );
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(player != null){
                   try{
                       Message msg = new Message();
                       msg.what = player.getCurrentPosition();
                       handler.sendMessage(msg);
                       positionBar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());
                       Thread.sleep(1000);
                   }catch (InterruptedException e){

                   }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
     private Handler handler = new Handler(){
         @Override
         public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
             int currentPosition = msg.what;
             positionBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
         }
     };`
```